# How to join multiple rows by continue from and to id columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a scenario where I need to find the start date and end date from multiple rows which are tied by continued_from and continued_to date fields in Oracle.
result should look like

```
ID  STARTDATE   ENDDATE     
--  ----------  ----------      
 3  01/01/1000  12/31/9999

ID  STARTDATE   ENDDATE     CONT_FROM_ID  CONT_TO_ID
--  ----------  ----------  ------------  -----------
 1  01/01/1000  10/10/1999          NULL            2    
 2  10/10/1999  11/11/2000             1            3
 3  11/11/2000  12/31/9999             2         NULL
```

Comment: Have you checked the docs on recursive queries? using CONNECT BY is one way of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's hierarchical query syntax makes it easy to walk the tree from parent to child. The analytical `lead()` and `lag()` functions track the next and previous IDs.

```
select c23.id
       , c23.startdate
       , c23.enddate
       , lag(c23.id) over (partition by p23.id order by c23.id) as cont_from_id 
       , lead(c23.id) over (partition by p23.id order by c23.id) as cont_to_id
from p23
     join c23 on p23.startdate <= c23.startdate
      and p23.enddate >= c23.enddate
order by c23.id
/
```

Here is a test using your sample data:

```
SQL> select c23.id
  2         , c23.startdate
  3         , c23.enddate
  4         , lag(c23.id) over (partition by p23.id order by c23.id) as cont_from_id 
  5         , lead(c23.id) over (partition by p23.id order by c23.id) as cont_to_id
  6  from p23
  7     join c23 on p23.startdate <= c23.startdate
  8     and p23.enddate >= c23.enddate
  9  order by c23.id
 10  /         

        ID STARTDATE ENDDATE   CONT_FROM_ID CONT_TO_ID
---------- --------- --------- ------------ ----------
         1 01-JAN-00 10-OCT-99                       2
         2 10-OCT-99 11-NOV-00            1          3
         3 11-NOV-00 31-DEC-99            2

SQL>
```